# How to get the header names and its type from csv file

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have trying to get all headers names from my .csv file

The `apex.parser` truncates my columname names if is greater then 27

**My code :**

```
select *
      from table(
                  apex_data_parser.get_columns(
                      apex_data_parser.discover(
                          p_content => blob,
                          p_file_name=>'emp.csv' )));
```

My data in file

```
NAME,AGE,DEMO_XYZS_HESF_ASDFGH_DIRSHRT,DEMO_N,D_NO
..................................................
..................................................
Some amount of data
..................................................
..................................................
```

When I run the above query it give me details of table structure and its type but my column : `DEMO_XYZS_HESF_ASDFGH_DIRSHRT` is getting truncated as showing it as `DEMO_XYZS_HESF_ASDFGH_DIRSH`

Is their any alternate way to get the `colum_name` and its types ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/Data-Types.html#GUID-55057C52-3A39-4F89-BF6A-6E66C920558C): `type t_file_column is record(col_seq pls_integer, name varchar2(128),...` So it should not be truncated